# chrome.action.onClicked or browserAction.onClicked is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a function execute when clicking the extension's icon in the toolbar(on the right corner). I added `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` in background.js file but it is not working. please help me.

Ultimately, My goal is to set a different icon by HTML element in `http://localhost:3000` that I use in the iframe tag.
(check there is a specific element in localhost:3000 -> set icon)

The reference that I follow:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:a%20browser%20action%20which%20changes%20its%20icon%20when%20clicked

my code is below.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "test",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  console.log('test for browser action');
});
```

**popup.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <iframe src="http://localhost:3000" width="400" height="600"></iframe>
  <script src="./background.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `default_popup` in manifest.json disables `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` (MV2) as well as `chrome.action.onClicked` (ManifestV3) event.

**Solution:** simply put the code in popup.js and load it as any other script in popup.html.

Warning! The "code" means the inner contents of onClicked listener, so don't add chrome.action.onClicked.addListener itself to popup.js.

popup.html

```html
  <script src=popup.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
document.body.append('This will run every time the popup is opened');
// note that `document` and `window` refers to the popup not to the web page
```

To inspect the popup and its console, right-click inside the popup, then click "inspect".

Note that you don't need the background script for this. The background script runs in a hidden background page so it should never be used anywhere else. Remove it from popup.html.

P.S. You're using the wrong [reference extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples). Search for `popup.html` using the built-in browser search via Ctrl-F (**not** the search input on the page).

Comment: thanks for the feedback :) 
I will search for the reference more. 
One question, if I want to put a number badge on the icon by the number of unread messages(element), what should I search for this case??

Comment: See chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText

Comment: @wOxxOm it doesn't work when I put my code `chrome.action.onClicked` in `popup.js`. Nothing happens. Any guesses?

Comment: @RohitKumar, put the code from onClicked without onClicked itself.